# Intellij Idea + Scala + Xfatal-warnings

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am using an SBT project inside IntelliJ Idea 14.

My `build.sbt` contains the following options:

```
scalacOptions := Seq(
  "-deprecation"
  , "-feature"
  , "-unchecked"
  , "-Xfatal-warnings"
  , "-Xlint"
  , "-Ywarn-numeric-widen"
  , "-Ywarn-value-discard"
  , "-Yno-adapted-args"
  , "-Ywarn-dead-code"
)
```

and when I build my project with `sbt compile` I get what I want: warnings as errors, etc.

However when I build/rebuild the project in Idea I don't even have a "Messages" window unless my code doesn't compile.

When I go to the Scala Compiler preferences I see all these options correctly imported into the "Additional Compiler Options" field in Idea.

What is the way to make Idea and SBT behave exactly in the same way?

**UPDATE** It works in Idea 13, but *not* in Idea 14

Comment: Have you opened a bug with JetBrains? (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newissue)

Comment: It was a bug. Fixed in 1.1.3
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7928